Reducing a bibtex file to the bibliography items actually cited
Assume a cumulative bibtex file (MyLibrary.bib) that contains the citation information of 1,000 references. Further, assume a LaTeX document (main.tex) that cites exactly 50 of the 1,000 references via \citep{} and invokes a \bibliography{MyLibrary} at the end.
Is there a way to automatically reduce MyLibrary.bib to the 50 references actually cited in main.tex?

If you're using regular bibtex methods (not biblatex + biber) you can use the bibexport command to create a .bib file based on your source file.  Assuming your file is called main.tex, then after compiling the document issue the following command:
bibexport -o main.bib main.aux

This will read your document's .aux file and produce a new .bib file (in this example named main.bib) which contains just the cited items.

I had no idea it would be this straightforward. Thank you point out bibexport.

In case you are using Biber rather than BibTeX, you can use Biber itself to create the .bib. Assuming your .tex file is called main.tex and you have compiled it successfully to create the .bcf:
$ biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve main.bcf

will create the .bib file. --output_resolve ensures that cross-references, sets, xdata etc. within the source .bib file or files will be resolved in the output file.
Use -o or --output-file if you want to specify the output file name. Use --help for more information, including ways to translate Unicode characters into BibTeX-safe characters etc.
